# Hadoop - cannot catch ioexception while inserting to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, ioexception

I use Hadoop 1.2.1 and perform a 'map only' job basically mapping log entries into a mysql table. One of the extracted field is an ip address, sometimes it is too long than the column length in the table and IOException occurs. I cannot catch and handle it despite of try-catch clause in map function. Code below:

```
public class LogEntriesMapper extends
    Mapper<Object, Text, LogEntry, NullDBWritable> {

private static Pattern p1 = Pattern
        .compile([…]);

private final static NullDBWritable nullDB = new NullDBWritable();
private LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    super.setup(context);
    p1 = Pattern.compile([...);
}

@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String entry = value.toString();

    Matcher matcher = p1.matcher(entry);

    if (matcher.find()) {

        String date = ...
        String ip = ...
        [extracting fields]

        logEntry.setDate(date);
        logEntry.setIp(ip);
        logEntry.setClient(client);
        logEntry.setSession(session);
        logEntry.setReal_time(real_time);

        try {
            context.write(logEntry, nullDB);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to save entry: " + logEntry);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

And syslog:

> 2014-01-07 15:38:08,908 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,233 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,354 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/logs/20130718.txt:0+49101
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,672 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,675 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev fbd3aa777e0ad06bce75c6aff8c91c7c68eb596b]
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,788 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1304)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1296)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:5028)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat$DBRecordWriter.close(DBOutputFormat.java:98)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1793)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:779)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,789 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Ignoring exception during close for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector@6dac133e
>   java.io.IOException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat$DBRecordWriter.close(DBOutputFormat.java:103)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1793)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:779)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,823 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
>
> **2014-01-07 15:38:09,855 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:mateuszmurawski cause:java.io.IOException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ip' at row 1**
>
> **2014-01-07 15:38:09,855 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
>   java.io.IOException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ip' at row 1**
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat$DBRecordWriter.close(DBOutputFormat.java:103)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
>
> 2014-01-07 15:38:09,861 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task

Comment: Can you show us the exception? Maybe its not an `IOException`?

Comment: @whoAmI
Just added after code.